# string that has been used in parseInt - get string value back again

Tags: javascript

Simple question  -

How do I convert a string that has been through parseInt back to it' string value?

```
var myInt = parseInt('J', 36); //19
var myString = myInt.toString(); //returns "19" I would like it to return "J"
```

Can I do it with longer strings?

```
var myInt = parseInt("Jon o'reiley", 36); //25511
```

Comment: Are you looking at encoding something in base36?

Comment: `parseInt("Jon o'reiley", 36) === parseInt("Jon", 36)`, because a space is not a valid character in base-36.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When converting a string to an int, information of the base the string used is lost. Also any data that was ignored while parsing is lost.

However, just like `parseInt` `toString` has a *base* argument, too:

```
myInt.toString(36);
```

Demo from the JS shell:

```
js> (19).toString(36)
"j"
js> parseInt('abc+foo', 36).toString(36)
"abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Once an object has been converted to an integer, any other information is lost.

You would have to store `J` in a seperate object if you wish to access this later.